# Unexpected behaviour while checking cookie

Tags: php

My login verify script -

`if($pass == $hash)
setcookie("cookiename",$cookieVal);`

This stores the cookie in the broswer. No problems with this; I have checked it myself.

However in a different page when I check to see if the cookie exists, it returns false.

`if(isSet($_COOKIE['cookiename'])) echo "Cookie is set";
else echo "Not set";`

The above code prints "Not set" in the broswer window.

Also, if I try `echo $_COOKIE['cookiename'];`, the ouput is an error **Notice: Undefined index: cookiename**

Apparently the browser (Firefox) cannot identify the cookie, although I can see it present when I check my broswer's options tab! Later, I also tried in Chrome and IE - same issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Update: When I added `if(isSet($_COOKIE['cookiename'])) echo "Set";` to the end of the login verify script, my cookie was detected ("Set" was printed)! But it isn't being detected in any other page.

Comment: You would not be seeing `Undefined index` with an `isset()` call as avoiding that notice is one of its purposes. Something else is wrong...

Comment: Other reasons a cookie may not come back - the domain name is different - you didn't specify the path, so verify the cookie's path in Firefox.

Comment: Can you share the two url's in question? (the one where the cookie is being set and the one where it would be readed back), i'm suspecting that the default path prevents the cookie to be sent to the second page.

Comment: Use `isset` instead of 'isSet'.

Comment: @Shahid Strange as it looks, function names are actually case-insensitive in PHP.

Comment: By default the setcookie() function expires the cookie when you leave the site. Are you browsing away and then going back?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sorry, my mistake. isset does not throw any `undefined index` error. `echo $_COOKIE['cookiename'];` does. Modified the question accordingly.

Comment: @Neuticle Nope, I am not browsing away. Besides, I had already tried setting the cookie for a certain time; but there was no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, cookies are only available at the path in which they're specified.  You should see a `Path` column in Firebug/Chrome that will show you a path.  To make a cookie accessible on your entire domain (not including subdomains), use `setcookie("cookiename", $cookieVal, strtotime('+1 year), '/');`

Comment: Yup. It's working. Thanks a lot.
But what will my 3rd parameter (time) be if I want the cookie to be set only for the duration of the session?

Comment: @gdebojyoti No problem!  From the setCookie documentation: `If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).` - http://php.net/setcookie

Comment: Just came across it myself too. `setcookie("cookiename",$cookieVal,0,'/');` But thanks, anyway. :-)
Everything's working fine now. That settles my cookie issue.